# Process running on EC2 instance stops when get disconnected from EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jar, process

I am running a Java CLI utility tool on an EC2 instance. It does some process and it writes the result to the console and also to a log file. I am running it with the following command:

```
java -jar <jar_file_name> |& tee output_file.txt
```

This processes should run for a few days. But when I get disconnected (the SSH session is closed) from the EC2 instance the process stops. How can I make the process running even when I get disconnected? (or turn off my local machine)

Comment: SO probably isn't a great resource for this.  You want a tool like `screen` (as mentioned in the answer), or `tmux`.  You can also use `nohup` with process management to run the process in the background, even when disconnected.  Also, a tool like `mosh` might help if you're losing an SSH connection.  You might also consider `cron` if it's going to be run often.  Or some combination of all of the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `Screen` command. This allows you to create a virtual, detached terminal session that is retained even if your SSH connection closes. The screen's processes continue to execute gracefully in the background.

(Screen is not pre-installed on all systems. See your distribution's documentation for installation instructions).

Create new session:

`screen -S java_session`

*(Run your java script here.)*

To detach (go back to SSH):

`CTRL + A + D`

To re-attach (on new SSH session):

`screen -r`

More information on Screen: [Documentation](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)

Answer (score 2):

Try nohup along with job launch command, nohup best suited for long running jobs, irrespective of SSH session it runs.

```
nohup java -jar cloud-config-server/target/*.jar > logs/cloud-config-server.log 2>&1 &
```

Documentation: https://linuxize.com/post/linux-nohup-command/